# ASP.NET Web Forms - Client side validation not working when field populated via jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have the following ASP.Net WebForm where the `Address` field is a required field. The `Address` field is populated via jQuery with the value of the `Location` field.

When I click submit without filling in any fields, the client side validation fires and we get the error message displayed below the `Address` control.

If I now enter a value into the `Location` field, the jQuery fires and the `Address` field is populated with a value but the previous error message doesn't clear - It only clears when I manually enter a value?

```html
<div>
    <label>Location</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Location" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter location"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    <label >Address</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Enter the address"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Address is Required" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="Address" CssClass="field-validation-error" EnableClientScript="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />  

<script>
    $("#Location").on('change', function (e) {
        var location =  $("#Location").val();
        $("#Address").val(location);
    });
</script>
```

How can I fix this so that if a client side error is displayed below a control, that it clears the error message if the validation logic is fullfilled via jquery as in the example above?

Comment: After assigne Address remove error label like this shoud work for you. `$("#Address").next('label').remove();`

Comment: @Shree why would i remove label? The markup generated by asp.net webforms is: `<span id="RequiredFieldValidator5" class="field-validation-error" style="display:inline;">Address is Required</span>` . Plus that is not a clean way to fix this if I have a dozen fields that are prepopulated in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually enter the value in the `Address` input the `change` event gets triggered when the input loses focus or you press enter. This doesn't happen when using the jQuery `val()` method.

To get it to work you have two options, either manually trigger the `change` event:

**Option 1: jQuery solution triggering change event**

```
$("#Location").on('change', function (e) {
    var location =  $("#Location").val();
    $("#Address").val(location).trigger("change");
});
```

Or alternatively you can manually call the Webforms validation methods directly. This is a bit more risky as there's no guarantee these methods won't change in the future, but I've included it for completeness as it can be useful in some situations.

**Option 2: call Webforms validation method to trigger a revalidation**

```
$("#Location").on('change', function (e) {
    var location =  $("#Location").val();
    $("#Address").val(location);
    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        Page_ClientValidate();
    }
});
```

I've chosen the `Page_ClientValidate` method here which will revalidate all validators for the given validation group (validation group not supplied here as it's not applicable). This is one of the simpler and safer methods to call, in more complex scenarios you may want `ValidatorValidate()` or one of the other other methods in WebUIValidation.js instead. Happy to expand on that, but I think it's out of the scope of the question.

I prefer option 1 as it's simpler and less open to being broken in the future by Webforms changes. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#Location").on('change', function (e) {
        var location =  $("#Location").val();
        $("#Address").val(location);
$("#Form id").data('validator').resetForm();
    });
```

try this,it will work